# display the cab with the highest overall maintenance cost

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I'm not sure how to get the max of the sum. I thought i could just display it in descending order and then use "rownum=1" but that didnt work. Any suggestions? Here's my code.

```
select ca_make,  sum(ma_cost)
from cab join maintain on ca_cabnum = ma_cabnum 
Where rownum =1
group by ca_make
order by sum(ma_cost) desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROWNUM() is applied before the ORDER BY.  You need to use a sub-query:

```
select * from (
    select ca_make,  sum(ma_cost)
    from cab join maintain on ca_cabnum = ma_cabnum 
    group by ca_make
    order by sum(ma_cost) desc
    )
where rownum = 1
```

---

There are several different ways of implementing [top-n] queries in Oracle.  [Find out more by searching SO for [oracle] [top-n].](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+top-n?sort=votes)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably want to use `LEFT JOIN`. By using `JOIN`, you're excluding all cabs that have had *no* maintenance at all.  (obviously, this won't matter for finding the *highest* cost, but it will make a difference when looking for the lowest cost; and it would seriously skew any stats you tried to compile from this query).

Now, to answer your question... try this:

```
select * from
  (select ca_make,  sum(ma_cost)
  from cab 
    left join maintain on ca_cabnum = ma_cabnum 
  group by ca_make
  order by sum(ma_cost) desc)
where rownum = 1
```

[here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) is a good explanation of `ROWNUM`.  Your case is addressed specifically, a little less than half-way down the page (but the whole page is probably worth a read, if you're going to use the feature).